# How can i get 100 records at a time from redis database having different keys?

Tags: java, redis

There are different keys inserted into redis database.I want to process that data using multithreading.But all threads will peek same data as there is no flag to update in redis database.

There are 10000 data in redis database but how can pick only 1000 data out of it if i don't know the keys;

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a set (or sorted set) to process your queue.
The population can be done with:
http://redis.io/commands/sadd
To remove your values, each worker can use:
http://redis.io/commands/spop
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hash or sorted set to store keys.
To iterate over  hash or sorted set  use hscan or zscan with  count = 1000

http://redis.io/commands/scan [read here](http://redis.io/commands/scan)

hopes it helps